# Multiple Parallel Websocket connections to SignalR hub in JMeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter, signalr, jmeter-plugins

We are trying to load test our login workflow, by simulating 50+ users logging into our front-end, via the API calls. As part of the login process, we make a websocket connection to a SignalR hub(Connect). We then send a call over the websocket connection to a custom endpoint in SignalR(Login), used to add some data to the Redis cache, then do some stuff which isn't important, then send a call to a different custom endpoint over the websocket connection(Logoff) and then Disconnect the websocket connection.

So my question is multi-part:

- How do we create a websocket connection from within JMeter?
- How do we make a call to a custom endpoint over the websocket connection in JMeter
- How do we do this for multi users simulated to be running in parallel, so we can test the load? In other words, we need multiple websocket connections open / alive from JMeter so we can test the load.

Note: Please be aware, I'm asking this on behalf of the load tester/JMeter developer, but because they are new to Stack Overflow, and I understand the SignalR side, I've been asked to log it. I know zip about JMeter, so please handle me like a noob trying to help someone solve a frustrating but important problem.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter per se doesn't support [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), you will need a special [plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) if you want to enable this functionality.

The most advanced, comprehensive and supported as of now is [JMeter WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/), it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Once you install the plugin and restart JMeter you will see several new samplers which will allow to open connection, send request, read response, and close connection.

Unfortunately I cannot guide you further because I don't know the specifics of your application, just look into your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or other [sniffer tool](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/network-packet-sniffers/) and configure JMeter to send the same requests as your browser (or other application) does.

More information:

- [Test SignalR Performance with JMeter](https://medium.com/@goldberg_rui/test-signalr-performance-with-jmeter-59083554f917)
- [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers)
- [`samples` directory](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/samples/) contains several example test plans covering different scenarios

Comment: Awesome - thank you so much - this does already help quite a lot! I'll pass all the info along to the tester / JMeter person, and I'll mark this as the answer if it solves our issue :-) But again, thanks for the assistance - the guys have been struggling to find info for a while now.